# Model _beforeSave observer can't save time

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, model, date, datepicker

## Synopsis

I have a date field in my admin form but when I save this date & time, I then have an observer that runs on my model `_beforeSave` which corrects the format for MySQL.  Although in the database and in the fields after reload, the time is missing.

**Observer**

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('', 'Some_Banners') . '/Model/Slide.php';

class My_Banner_Model_slide extends Some_Banners_Model_Slide
{
    public function _beforeSave()
    {
        parent::_beforeSave();

        if (preg_match('/^\d{2}([\/]+)\d{2}\1\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}\:+\d{1,2}$/', $this->getEndAt())) {
            $endDate = preg_replace('/^(\d{2}?)\/(\d{2}?)\/(\d{4}?)\s+(\d{1,2}?)\:+(\d{1,2}?)$/', '\\3-\\2-\\1 \\4:\\5:00', $this->getEndAt());
            $this->setData('end_at', $endDate);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Please note: when I execute the following debugging the data is correct as expected, something happens after this method before the save occurs.

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{2}([\/]+)\d{2}\1\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}\:+\d{1,2}$/', $this->getEndAt())) {
    Zend_Debug::dump( $this->getEndAt() );
    // Output: 13/05/2013 12:30

    $endDate = preg_replace('/^(\d{2}?)\/(\d{2}?)\/(\d{4}?)\s+(\d{1,2}?)\:+(\d{1,2}?)$/', '\\3-\\2-\\1 \\4:\\5:00', $this->getEndAt());

    Zend_Debug::dump( $endDate );
    // Output: 2015-05-13 12:30:00

    $this->setData('end_at', $endDate);

    Zend_Debug::dump( $this->getEndAt() );
    // Output: 2015-05-13 12:30:00
}
```

Comment: Zend_Db caches the database tables, did you make sure you went to "Cache Management" and flushed the "Magento Cache"?

Comment: It's mysteriously worked, I did not clear the cache.  Also, in my case the field was added and the date was being saved just not the *time*. Maybe it was cache.

Comment: It could well be. Did you change the field from a DATE to a DATETIME maybe?

Comment: Now you mention it, that would make sense.  i had a date field, then changed to datetime didn't clear the cache so magento remembered the field as 'date'.  Although, I never cleared the cache when it started to work - which is the confusing thing.

Comment: The cache must have an expiry. I m glad your issue is resolved anyway, I will add my comment as an answer, if you wouldnt mind accepting it so we can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_Db caches the database tables, make sure you go to "Cache Management" and flush the "Magento Cache"